# HTTP interceptor getting status 0 on failed request using Angular 2,4,6,7,8,9 TypeScript

Tags: angular, http, typescript, web-deployment, angular-http-interceptors

I have following implementation of HTTP interceptors with `Angular ^4.3.6`.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      console.log(evt);//this logs the success message properly
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        //Keep going
      }
    },err => {
    console.log(err);
    //this logs the error but don't have useful info in it.
    });

}
}
```

On the successful http call, I get following members of `evt` which are valid on the first console.log.

```
ok:true
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:4
```

]

But on failure I don't have proper status code from the `err` block on the second console.log but have following message in DEV console from ZONE.js

> zone.js:2263 OPTIONS http://localhost:7001/coreRobo/neuralProcess 404(Not Found)

```
name:"HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status:0
statusText:"Unknown Error"
```

I am not sure what I am missing here but I wanted that status to give me something valid like 404,403 or heck 500 when it clearly is that what is happening.

I just wanted those values so that I can show proper message to the UI and help client not panic on failure.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what produces this error? Are you sure you actually get a 404, 403 or 500 error from the server? If you can't even send the request to the server (network issue, DNS issue, etc.), you can't possibly get an HTTP status code.

Comment: @JBNizet  is on to something. I've had the same experience as you and it was due to failure to reach the server. If it is something else then the error is likely server-side not client-side.

Comment: I see there is 404 error message in browser's console logged from zone.js .Clearly it is not server issue. Cannot we catch those status codes? What is the point of interceptors if it doesn't catch status code after the service call?

Comment: Any error in the console? Are you sure the response is valid. For example, does it contain invalid JSON although the content type is set to JSON? Can you reproduce it in a plunkr?

Comment: I shut down my server and zone.js consoled 404. I would like to have interceptor catch that status code. Apparently, it just returns 0. I don't think I can reproduce this in plunkr. :(

Comment: As you see, the request that causes a 404 is an OPTIONS request. It's not your actual request. The browser sends the pre-flight request to conform with the CORS specifications. Since it doesn't receive a valid response, it is not allowed to even send the actual request, and there is thus no response for your request, hence the bizarre status code.

Comment: I have the same issue, I receive a 404 from the server (without the CORS) and the status code in my interceptor is 0 (when I want 404)

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If You are using **CORS** you should check "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" in your server configuration.

I Solved this on my **nginx** server adding:

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" * always;
```

I missed the "**always**" parameter which caused me the same problem as yours.

You should pay attention to the value of the header "*" in my example.

The value must contain the list of allowed origins.

Comment: I would disagree that this is the best configuration option. It leaves your website vulnerable. You should always whitelist a set of domains instead of allowing all of them

Comment: What could be other soulution ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was causing the issue.. Its a server side issue. You need to set the CORS middleware first then the remaining API middlewares.

Please note i am working with Laravel 5.6 + Angular 5

### Wrong Code

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
```

### Currect Code

```
'api' => [
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings'
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net core API  I solved this problem by writing "UseCors" before UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization, mainly because when the authentication service is before CORS service when the authentication service goes back directly, it doesn't set the CORS header for it.

Comment: how would you solve this using NestJS?