# Angular 5 Http Interceptor don't detect response header (POST)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I'm not able to get the custom response header in interceptor when i console log it. [console logged the interceptor httpResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlHLv.jpg)

**''Console log response''**

HttpResponse {
headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", ok: true, …
}

HttpHeaders
lazyInit
:
ƒ ()
lazyUpdate
:
null
normalizedNames
:
Map(0) {}
**proto**
:
Object
ok
:
true
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
4

We also added the *Access-control-expose-header* in the server side. Still i'm not getting the response. Not sure whether i miss something in the interceptor method.

**Interceptor method**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.employee.tonguestun.com; version=1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        });

    return next.handle(req)
        .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            console.log(ev)
            if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log(ev.headers);
            }
            // return ev;
        })

}
```

[interceptor fuction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wappX.jpg)

**Custom header in network tab**

access-control-allow-credentials: true

access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS

access-control-allow-origin: *

access-control-expose-headers: access-token,client,expiry,token-type,uid

access-token: haIXZmNWSdKJqN2by7JH1g

cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

client: j_2dxD7NVMjGeX8BbBuELA

content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

expiry: 1525931943

[getting custom headers in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdUs2.jpg)

Also this is my service call, added observe 'response' in the call too.

**Service call**

```
return this.http.post(`${environment.baseUrl}${environment.signup}`, data, {observe: "response"})
  .map(response => response);
```

[service call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJM3j.jpg)

**AppModule.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppInterceptor } from './services/app-interceptor.service';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module'; 
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HomeModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuardService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Help me please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

[This implementation](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) of HttpInterceptor should be of help to you. The [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) class has a **Headers** property which will help you read your response header.

Comment: I'm able to get the Response body and header. But the header contains empty data.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i have faced. If you call your service via `http` it will not work, because interceptor not familiar with it please use `httpClient` then automatically interceptor detect your each request, and interceptor also send your headers to server side

**AppHttpInterceptor.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import {
        HttpInterceptor,
        HttpRequest,
        HttpResponse,
        HttpErrorResponse,
        HttpHandler,
        HttpEvent
    } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
    import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router'


    @Injectable()
    export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(private router: Router){

        }
        headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Token': localStorage.getItem("Token")
        });
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            console.log("intercepted request ... ");

            // Clone the request to add the new header.
            const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("Token", localStorage.getItem("Token")) });

            console.log("Sending request with new header now ...");

            //send the newly created request
            return next.handle(authReq)
                .catch(err => {
                    // onError
                    console.log(err);
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        console.log(err.status);
                        console.log(err.statusText);
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            window.location.href = "/login";
                        }
                    }
                    return Observable.throw(err);
                }) as any;
        }
    }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from "angular2-toaster";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule,HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AppHttpInterceptor} from './Common/AuthInterceptor';
import { AppRoutes } from '../app/Common/Routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpModule,HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
    this.httpClient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe(
      success => {
        console.log("Successfully Completed");
        console.log(success);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"; .
Just in constructor named it as http. Still i'm not getting the response.

Comment: Ok, i have a solution, but i can send you after few hours. Thanks @SankarNamachivayam

Comment: Yes, i checked. I actually used HttpClient only. The problem is from server side. 

This helped us in solving this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539194/8587798. We missed the 'always' keyword in nginx config.

Thanks for your time and appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Welcome @SankarNamachivayam

Answer (score 0):

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47539194/8587798) helped us solve this issue. The problem is in the nginx configuration. We missed always keyword in access-control-expose-header.

Answer (score 0):

The headers map is lazy loading, so you need to trigger the map to load content in order to list the headers.

For example, call `headers.keys()` or get a specific header by key `headers.get('name-of-key')`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

from the docs https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

```
const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
    });

    // send cloned request with header to the next handler.
    return next.handle(authReq);
```

see that use a new variable, see how change the headers using set over req.headers

Comment: tried it, didn't work. I can able to set headers in request. I'm not getting response header when i console it in cloned request's next handler.

Comment: the function "intercept" is executed?, see that if you want to use over all the request you must import HTTP_INTERCEPTORS and declare in your app.module.ts

Comment: yes, it is executed. Have updated app.module.ts in the question, please check.

Comment: use newreq=req.clone... and return next.handle(newreq). I's only an idea, I don't be sure that work