# HttpInterceptor > HttpErrorResponse does not return the result of the request

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I need to refresh my token, but HttpErrorResponse does not return the result of the request.

get http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pdv
return response : {"token_error":"token_expired"}

but, when my token is expired I receive (Cross-Origin Request   Blocked). just this case.

here is my config
config/cors I'm used barryvdh/laravel-cors

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
```

middlewareGroups

```
'api' => [
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

I try get response with (*obs: console.log(error.error) is undefined*)

```
const error = (typeof errorResponse.error !== 'object') ? JSON.parse(errorResponse.error) : errorResponse.error;
                    console.log(error.error)
```

```
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    // return next.handle(request)
                    const error = (typeof errorResponse.error !== 'object') ? JSON.parse(errorResponse.error) : errorResponse.error;
                    console.log(error.error)
                    // return ;
                    // || (errorResponse.status === 0)
                    if (errorResponse.status === 401 && error.error === 'token_expired') {
                        const http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);
                        return http.post<any>(`${API}/auth/refresh`, {})
                            .pipe(
                                flatMap(data => {
                                    localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
                                    const authRequest = request.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.token}` } })
                                    return next.handle(authRequest)
                                })
                            )
                    }

                    return throwError(errorResponse);
                })
            )

    }
```

I need to get this return "token_expired" then refresh token.

console.log(error.error)

[image]

console.log(errorResponse)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean  console.log(error.error) prints nothing?

Comment: Do you get any response at all? Check the browsers developer console and network tab. This might be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. [About the same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/9423231).

Comment: @SumitParakh yes, print undefined.

Comment: So the error code part is hit though? Can you post the error exactly how you receive it?

Comment: @AJT_82 just error.error is undefined. but api response is  {"token_error":"token_expired"} i need get this response.

Comment: OK... so is it an error response or 200 response? How does the response look like, can you post an image?

Comment: or, show what `console.log(errorResponse)` produces.

Comment: @AJT_82 Console https://i.imgur.com/Zrduzb7.png

Comment: if `console.log(errorResponse)` produces `undefined` you are not getting anything clearly. Can't be... has to be a status or something. Does `console.log(errorResponse)` really produce that?

Comment: @AJT_82 console.log(errorResponse) https://i.imgur.com/2tUT6gN.png

Comment: How are you adding the `HandleCors` middleware? Maybe it's in the wrong order. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212896/9423231

Comment: What OAuth provider are you using? I think you have to add CORS support to those routes specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are already parsing the error object and then saving the parsed result to error variable.  So in that case, why do you need to use **error.error** ? Can't you just use **error** variable like this?:--

Replace

```
console.log(error.error);
```

By

```
console.log(error);
```