# warnings and errors on google chrome in angular stackblitz project

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http-error, stackblitz

I get errors and warnings when I load the web page related to an angular project on stackblitz. These errors happen in google chrome, everything works fine in firefox!
**warnings**

```
The FetchEvent for "https://2.38.65.136:5001/getBrands" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith()
```

note:this happen for every http request

**https errors**

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://angula-carsmarketplace.stackblitz.io/_sw_.js' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure resource 'http://andreadicioccio.byethost10.com/CarsImages/images/callCenterADS.jpg'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

note: I know this error, and I understand it but in firefox there aren't. so I'm dumbfounded.

**error interceptor messages**

```
Http failure response for https://2.38.65.136:5001/getBrands
```

note:this happen for every http request.The requests never reaches the server, I don't know why

all this on firefox doesn't exist, everything works fine! I would like to know how to solve the main problem, that is, the fact that the request never reaches the server. Since everything works on firefox, I think the problem is with the chrome settings.
This is [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angula-carsmarketplace)
Thanks

Comment: The error occurs in both chrome and firefox, I have checked it now. This error is due to CORS. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212896/4901118

Comment: In firefox disable all plugins and see if the error occurs, if not then maybe you have some plugin for CORS, this is just a guess.

Comment: I ll see but the server is on my computer, it could be that my pc was turned off.

Comment: I did had already configured the server for CORS. I sew, I have not CORS plugin in firefox